# How do I create a new command \listofcodes in latex?

Tags: floats, table-of-contents, listings

In addition to tables and figures, I have a bunch of code pieces. Just like follows:

```
    \begin{figure}
    \lstinputlisting[
    language=C++, breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    frame=single,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    caption={Data acquisition code},
    label={code:data}]
    {codes/data.cpp}
\end{figure}
```

Those codes do not appear in table of figures or table of contents which is exactly what I want.

Now I want to create a new table of codes \listofcodes similar to \listoffigures. It should create a third table. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the `listings` package, then you have `\lstlistoflistings` to generate a *list of listings*. I see that you are enclosing your `lstinputlistings` in a `figure` environment; if the idea is to turn them into floats then you could use the `float` option; a little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

%A non-floating listing:
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Useless code one},label=uselessone]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}

%A floating listing:
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={Useless code two},label=uselesstwo]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: corrected the example according to Andrey Vihrov's comment.

Comment: This isn't the correct usage. `listings` has the `float` parameter.

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov: thanks. I've edited my answer accordingly.